# Multivariable Expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, covariance, correlation

$E(X)=x_1, E(Y)=y_1$

$Var(X)=x_2, Var(Y)=y_2$

correlation coefficient between X and Y $\rho(X,Y)=C$

need to find $E(Z)$ and $Var(Z)$ where $Z=aX+bY$

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm going by the following: E(X^2)=Var(X)+(E(X))^2 and E(XY)=Cov(X,Y)+E(X)*E(Y) and using linearity and basically expanding all the terms out.  It's just confusing due to the number of terms and orders of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the linearity property of expectation value 
$$E[aX+ bY]=aE[X]+bE[Y]$$
and use definition 
$$\textit{var}[aX+bY]=E[(aX+bY-E[aX+bY])^2]$$

Comment: doesnt that ignore the correlation coefficient?

Comment: i think it see it, its needed for the squares, E(X^2)=Var(X)+(E(X))^2 and E(XY)=Cov(X,Y)+E(X)*E(Y)  is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\operatorname{Var}Z=\operatorname{cov}(Z,Z)$.
Also, the covariance is linear in the sense that
$$
\operatorname{cov}(aX+bY, cW+dV) = ac\,\operatorname{cov}(X,W)+ad\,\operatorname{cov}(X,V)+bc\,\operatorname{cov}(Y,W)+bd\,\operatorname{cov}(Y,V)
$$
for any random variables $X,Y,W,V$ and any real numbers $a,b,c,d$. Hence,
$$
\operatorname{cov}(aX+bY,aX+bY)=a^2\operatorname{Var}X+ab\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)+ba\operatorname{cov}(Y,X)+b^2\operatorname{Var}Y.
$$
The correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is given by
$$
\operatorname{\rho}(X,Y)=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}X}\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}Y}}.
$$
Now we only need to use the given values to calculate $\operatorname{Var}Z$.